# Website "supervisor" in C#/.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm not sure what the technical name for what I'm looking for is, but this is what I'm trying to achieve:

I need to write a "client" for a specific website which uses Ajax/XHR for communication with the server.

My approach is to make a custom web browser that will run the JavaScript in the background, and I can show all the relevant information to the user. My first thought was to use hidden WebBrowser, however I'm not sure if it can achieve all the following:

- Denying requests (so that unnecessary content doesn't load)
- Inspecting (and possibly editing) XHR requests and responses
- Making custom JavaScript calls (using `javascript:` quasi-protocol is ok)
- Inspecting HTML elements' event listeners (so that I can call them)

Basically, I want functionality similar to that of Chrome's **Developer Tools**, in C#.

What's the easiest way of doing so, since my current idea is to use WebBrowser through a custom proxy, with hardcoded event listeners (manually found, hoping names don't change soon)?

Comment: Do you need to render the content of the watched website to the user? Or is the library handling the reading of it?

Comment: No, the point of the whole thing is to gather needed data from the page, and inspecting XHR is AFAIK easiest way of doing it, since all needed data is sent over it

Comment: Aha, then I think you could use a Rest library instead and do screen scraping. Is the target application using javascript heavily?

Comment: @EmilIngerslev If by "target application" you mean that website I'm targeting, then yes, in fact it's updating in real-time. To be worse, the page itself is just a bunch of tables, images and loading gifs, all data is loaded afterwards.  Page scraping would be hard even after loading, since a lot of "hints" like style classes and div names are seemingly randomly changing...

Comment: I can see your problem there. Any headless browser would make this task less heavy I think, but every headless browser I can think of (PhantomJs for one) is not .NET. You could build a PhantomJs script that you keep running interact with through C#, but again this is external dependency (which could be included as "tools" though)

Comment: @EmilIngerslev What about [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/)? Apparently it can be used as a headless browser. Also, performance is not the biggest concern, since rendering and discarding the page will probably end up being one of the faster things the application does

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76755/discussion-between-stargate-tabc-and-emil-ingerslev).

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to use C# and Chrome, go for [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp):

which is bindings for .NET and Chromium browser.

I think it could be a lot easier to use [Electron](https://github.com/atom/electron/) or [nw.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/), but these would require you code in javascript, which of cause also will make custom javascript calls easier.

*Side note: The new [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is actually built with Electron, so even microsoft uses that for doing javascript/web technology based apps.*

Comment: Using JavaScript sounds like a good idea, but the problem is that it's just a part of a larger application written in .NET. In fact, it's supposed to be a library.

Comment: Then I would go for the CefSharp. The is also Awesomium which is easier to get started with, but Chromium version is a way behind in that project.